# Salesforce Async API not enabled even if enabled on Enterprise edition

Tags: profile, permissions, bulk-api

I'm facing this issue on a customer enterprise edition. He's a system administrator and I checked his profile both in backend and through salesforce ui, and both are enabled (`PermissionsApiEnabled => true`), but I still get the error `Async API not enabled (FeatureNotEnabled)`, they have an "old ui", so I believe they have a very old Salesforce installation maybe?

I'm not sure what to do, but I would like to solve the problem for the customer and find a way to get their Bulk API working.

Should I ask them to contact salesforce support? Digging through the net, I read there is an "Organization wide" API Enabled flag, but I don't even know where to look for it. Is it only available to Salesforce Support maybe?

Comment: Is it just the async bulk API that isn't working?

Comment: Yes, I tested the rest API and it's working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm it was an issue with the organization itself, we had to ask to support to enable ASYNC Api for them and it worked.